# Determining area of regions in image based on user input with JavaFX

Tags: java, image-processing, javafx, javafx-8

**Introduction**

The title is a bit complicated so let's break it down:

1. I have an image submitted by a user
2. The image is a top view of a landscape featuring clearly marked regions. For example, if this was a park the image would be a top view of the parks layout.
3. I need to allow the user to classify different elements in the image and estimate the area occupied by those elements. Continuing with the park analogy; the park may have two pavilions and a sand volleyball court. I must allow the user to mark the points of interest (let's say the volleyball court) and compute their area (given the overall dimensions of the depicted park)

**Current Ideas**

I think I should create a buffered image and use that as the background of a canvas.

I'm not sure about the user input. My first idea was to have the users drag rectangles associated with a specific feature (ie. red rectangle for volleyball courts) to the region over the image. Rectangles work because the elements are mostly rectangular but I don't know that users can resize rectangles.

To reiterate, the main problem is determining the area occupied by physical structures in a given image. No machine vision, just plain old Mouse Events.

How should I be approaching the user input dilemma? Any APIs I should be digging through?

*Please let me know if I can improve the question and explanation.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287372/how-to-take-snapshot-of-selected-area-of-screen-in-javafx this post will help you

Comment: Thank you this may come in handy later. Unfortunately I don't see how this applies to calculating the area. Could you please explain?